Propagation of the expectation of a function with the path integral
I'm working on formulating some results in the path integral formulation and have encountered an object where I'm unsure as to what the correct treatment is:
$$\int dx_1\psi(0,x_1)\left(\int_{\tilde{x}(0)=x_1}^{\tilde{x}(t)=x_2} \mathcal{D}\tilde{x}\exp\left(iS[\tilde{x}]/\hbar\right)f(\tilde{x})\right).$$
From my interpretation, this is the propagation of the expectation value $\langle f(x)\rangle$ over all paths to a point $x_2$ (I think I'm forgetting a normalisation of 1/Z in there). Is this the correct interpretation of this object? Any further information would be helpful.

The integral over $x_1$ is an integral over initial conditions, and $\psi(0, x_1)$ is the wavefunction at $t=0$ that weights those initial conditions.
So your path integral computes something like
$$
\langle x_2, t | f(x) | \psi, 0\rangle
$$
where $|\psi, 0\rangle$ is the state that is described by the wavefunction $\psi$ at time $t=0$. In other words, in the position basis, $\langle x | \psi, 0\rangle = \psi(0, x)$.

Thank you! That's very helpful. Just one further question, if I were then to take the absolute value of your expression then integrate over $x_2$, would I recover the expectation value of $f$ for a state $|\psi(t)\rangle$?

So you want $\int d x_2 |\langle x_2, t| f(x)| \psi, 0\rangle|$? I don't think this has a simple interpretation in terms of expectation values. Among other reasons, the amplitude is complex but by taking the absolute value you've made the integrand positive, so you are projecting out some phase information.

Apologies I made a mistake in what I was asking, I meant $\int dx_2 \langle\psi,0|f(x)|x_2,t\rangle\langle x_2, t | f(x) | \psi, 0\rangle$ (so the absolute value squared). I'm unsure about these t's in the kets

I see. I think what you're basically asking is, given the initial wave function at time $0$ is $\psi(x)$, what is the expectation value for the operator $f(x)$, at time $t$. Let me think about it a bit though, I'm not 100% sure that's the right way to think about it.
